# How to reset password for Sequel Pro?

Tags: sql, database, sequelpro

It is unclear for me how to reset the password to access the Sequel Pro. Those are my settings:

- Name: localhost
- Host: 127.0.0.1
- Username: root
- Port: 8889

How to reset password/ solve this set up of Sequel Pro issue?

Answer (score 2):

Log in with your information above as usual.

Click on "Query".

Run the following query:

```
SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('yournewpassword');
```

Exit and log in with your info above and "yournewpassword".